# How do I enable the control bar for an .swf file?

Tags: video, flash, param

The code below works great except the user has to right click the video and then left click "play".  Is there a way to add the control bar via param?

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" 
width="360" height="270">

<param name="movie" value="File1.swf">

<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="play" value="False">
<param name="enabled" value="True">

<embed src="File1.swf" quality="high" 
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="360" height="280"></embed>

</object>
```

Comment: hmmm, very clean code indeed! something missing?

Comment: Don't use the <pre> tag to show your code in a Stack Overflow question/answer. Use the code button in the text editor.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to code a "control bar" yourself with ActionScript 3. There is no build-in control bar that you can turn on using a param.

You basically need to call `stop()` and `play()` on your main timeline from a play and pause button. Here is great guide for [Basics of movie clips on Adobe site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d9c.html).

Once you get that working, you may want to impliment a scrubber. So here is a good example: [GotoAndLearn.com - how to create scrub bar to control swf files](http://www.gotoandlearnforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=14554#p96467). The third post from the bottom has a FLA download that might help.